# Meteor.js + autoform a working contact form example

Tags: meteor

Can we get a complete contact form example for Meteor beginners?

**The steps so far.**

- Create the Schema
- Show the contact form in a template
- make sure the values are passed with a method
- Add required packages
- Create the helper for client side
- Create the method for server side (Sends the email)
- Show a message on success

Working from the info on https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#an-example-contact-form

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**both/collections/contact.coffee**

```
@Contacts = new Meteor.Collection('contacts')

Schemas.Contacts = new SimpleSchema
  name:
    type: String
    label: "Your name"
    max: 50
    optional: true
    autoform:
      placeholder: "John Doe"

  email:
    type: String
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    label: "E-mail address"
    optional: true
    autoform:
      placeholder: "John@doe.com"

  message:
    type: String
    label: "Message"
    max: 1000
    optional: true
    autoform:
      placeholder: "Message"
      rows: 3

Contacts.attachSchema(Schemas.Contacts)
```

**views/contact/contact.html**

```
<template name="contactPage">
  <h2>Get in Contact</h2>
  {{> quickForm
    schema=contactFormSchema
    id="contactForm"
    type="method"
    meteormethod="sendEmail"
    template="bootstrap3-horizontal"
    label-class="col-sm-3"
    input-col-class="col-sm-9"
  }}
</template>
```

**.meteor/packages**

```
coffeescript
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:simple-schema
aldeed:autoform
twbs:bootstrap
email
```

**views/contact/contact.coffee**

```
if Meteor.isClient
  Template.contactPage.helpers
    contactFormSchema: ->
      Schemas.Contacts
```

**server/contact-send.coffee**

```
if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.methods
    sendEmail: (doc) ->
    # Important server-side check for security and data integrity
    check doc, Schemas.contacts
    # Build the e-mail text
    text = 'Name: ' + doc.name + '\n\n' + 'Email: ' + doc.email + '\n\n\n\n' + doc.message
    @unblock()
    console.log "about to send the email"
    # Send the e-mail
    Email.send
      to: 'someone@somewhere.com'
      from: doc.email
      subject: 'Website Contact Form - Message From ' + doc.name
      text: text
```

Comment: The current code results in. Exception in delivering result of invoking 'sendEmail': Error: Match failed [400]

Comment: I'd like to see a contact form that also saves the doc. Maybe thats not considered a contact form but seems pretty standard to have a form save to the db then send some sort of notification .